# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048

Tags: laravel

el error se produce cuando intento ejecutar las factories de mi proyecto

aqui esta el error mas detallado:

```
 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'verification_token' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `email_verified_at`, `password`, `remember_token`, `verified`, `verification_token`, `admin`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Prof. Florida Stokes, osinski.lela@example.com, 2020-07-03 04:04:55, $2y$10$QvJVAUawIGPGGI0WqNP5m.EncKmtsHmGlltXdBuxrusz0dHB5BvfG, SkUNYWrC2y, 1, ?, true, 2020-07-03 04:04:55, 2020-07-03 04:04:55))
```

el problema es que 'verification_token' esta recibiendo '?' como parametro, como puedo resolverlo?

este es el codigo de mi factory

```
$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    static $password;
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        'verified' => $verificado = $faker->randomElement([User::USUARIO_VERIFICADO, User::USUARIO_NO_VERIFICADO]),
        'verification_token'=> $verificado == User::USUARIO_VERIFICADO ? null : User::generarVerificationToken(),
        'admin' => $faker->randomElement([User::USUARIO_ADMINISTRADOR, User::USUARIO_REGULAR]),
    ];
});
```

esta es la pulbic function con la obtengo valores al azar:

```
public static function generarVerificationToken()
    {
        return $random = Str::random(40);
    }
```

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro: *`Column 'verification_token' cannot be null`*  estás intentando guardar un valor `null` en la columna `verification_token` la cual en la definicion de la tabla tiene la restricción (constraint) `not null`. Entonces, o cambias esa restricción haciendo que esa columna admita nulos (si debe ser así, claro está) o revisas los datos que estás mandando, evitando que ese valor sea nulo.

Comment: si eso ya se, pero que estoy haciendo mal en la funcion generarVerificationToken(),? porque se supone que en la factory le digo a verification_token que tome el valor que le genere dicha funcion